# CheckBox Item in Custom Designed UITableViewCell , IPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have designed a custom table cell. which displays product information.

When i implement CellForRowAtIndexPath I am doing this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *sectionTableCellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"GLItemTableCellIdentifierNumber%d",indexPath.section];
//  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GLItemDetailsTableCellIdentifier"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sectionTableCellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) 
    {


        NSDictionary *dict = [self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
        ItemsListTableCell *cell = (ItemsListTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sectionTableCellIdentifier];              
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemsListTableCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) 
        {
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[ItemsListTableCell class]])
            {
                cell = (ItemsListTableCell *)oneObject;
            }
        }

        NSString *priceinfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%@",[dict objectForKey:@"CurrentPrice"]];
        NSString *sizeinfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Size: %@",[dict objectForKey:@"Size"]];

        NSString *upcInfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UPC: %@",[dict objectForKey:@"ID"]];
        NSString *strQuantity = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Quantity"]];

        cell.lblProductName.text = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
        cell.lblSize.text = sizeinfo;
        cell.lblBrand.text = [dict objectForKey:@"BrandName"];
        cell.lblProductCode.text = upcInfo;        
        cell.lblQuantity.text = strQuantity;        
        cell.lblPrice.text = priceinfo;
        cell.lblStoreName.text = [dict objectForKey:@"StoreName"];
        cell.isSelected = NO;
        [cell.btnSelected addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonTapped:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [upcInfo release];
        [priceinfo release];
        [strQuantity release];
        [sizeinfo release];
        return cell;
    }   
    return cell;
}
```

now for the click event I am doing

```
- (IBAction)cellButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIView *contentView = [sender superview];
    ItemsListTableCell *cell = (ItemsListTableCell *)[contentView superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSUInteger buttonRow = [[self.table
                             indexPathForCell:cell] row];
    NSUInteger buttonSection = [[self.table
                             indexPathForCell:cell] section];

    NSLog(@"Index Path Row : %d",buttonRow);
    NSLog(@"Index Path Section : %d",buttonSection);

    ItemsListTableCell *buttonCell =
    (ItemsListTableCell *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (buttonCell.isSelected == YES) 
    {
        buttonCell.isSelected = NO;
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-empty.png"] autorelease];
        [buttonCell.btnSelected setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        buttonCell.isSelected = YES;
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-full.png"] autorelease];
        [buttonCell.btnSelected setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    self.txtQuantity.text = buttonCell.lblQuantity.text;
    NSString *buttonTitle = buttonCell.lblProductName.text;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"You tapped the button"
                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"You tapped the button for %@", buttonTitle]
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

The Problem is when i click on check button it is going to the event. but I am unable to detect what is the parent cell . as there are some values in cell.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating such an event (IBAction), you could do all of these in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else 
    if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

}
```

If you want a checkmark of your own style, you could set them up here and finish off things. Makes stuff easier !

Comment: Actually i dont need to select entire row. Because entire row has some other events such as price or quantity update. I tested this solution with accessorytype it works in case or row selection. But my requirememt is to click on specified area of cell as my cell is also very big in size.